# How to call Python script from SAS JMP environment using jsl script

Tags: python, sas-jmp, jsl

I would like to run python script from SAS JMP environment using JSL. What are the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at SAS communities - that would be better source of information.

Some search shows that you can call python script from JSL. Here are two examples:

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Tip-How-to-execute-a-Python-script-in-SAS-Enterprise-Miner/ta-p/223761

https://community.jmp.com/t5/Discussions/Best-method-to-get-a-python-object-into-JMP/td-p/15158

Answer (score 0):

This JSL works in my hands. (JMP 13.2)

```
x = RunProgram(
    executable( "/Users/bywing/anaconda/bin/python" ),
    options( "/Users//bywing//BasicIrisExample.py" ),
    readfunction( "blob" )
);
```